# "Temp" directory in Windows, IO.getFile

Tags: firefox-addon

I would like to write to the C:\windows\temp directory (or it's configured equivalent) inside my Firefox-addon.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/FileGuide/FileWriting

Gives the impression that there are system independent names for these paths:

```
var file = IO.getFile("Desktop", "myinfo.txt");
var stream = IO.newOutputStream(file, "text");
stream.writeString("This is some text");
stream.close();
```

But I can't find any reference in the specified references, as to what "Desktop" points to. So that leaves me not knowing what exactly is referred to in the names given by the documentation.

**How to I use IO.getFile() to open a file in the windows global temp folder?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [Code snippets: File I/O](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Getting_special_files) on developer.mozilla.org. It answers your question (Matthew is right, it's "TmpD"), and provides many other file-related examples.

[edit] Oh, and does `IO` actually work for you? I thought it was [unavailable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIScriptableIO). [edit2] I added a warning at the top of the pages I could find, that mention it.

Comment: @Justin Alexander: I just linked to <https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2f%2fO#Getting_special_files>, it has the working code. If you're asking for the wrappers, I don't have the preferred one. I try to mimic whatever Firefox's code does -- if they come up with a standard wrapper, I'd use it.

Answer (score 1):

The keys are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IO_Guide%2f%2fDirectory_Keys).

I believe you want `TmpD`, which is listed [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/xpcom/io/nsDirectoryServiceDefs.h)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Writing stackoverflow.txt to TEMP dir
const { OS } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {})
const path = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.tmpDir, "stackoverflow.txt")
OS.File.writeAtomic(path, "Hello, StackOverflow!", {
    encoding: "utf-8",
    tmpPath: "stackoverflow.txt.tmp", // it's not necessary but I'd recommend to use it
}).then(() => console.log(path, "has been written"))
// C:\Users\traxium\AppData\Local\Temp\stackoverflow.txt has been written

// Reading stackoverflow.txt from TEMP dir
const { OS } = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {})
const path = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.tmpDir, "stackoverflow.txt")
OS.File.read(path, { encoding: "utf-8" }).then(txt => console.log(txt))
// "Hello, StackOverflow!"
```